# Microsoft Excel - Why is my graph not plotting correctly?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two columns of data,

the first column is Average RT, going from 2050 to 20450.
My second column is fraction, from 0.000000 to various decimals, but all add up to 1.

My aim is to plot the Average RT on X axis, and the corresponding fraction for that RT value on the Y axis.

But when I select both columns and plot, Im getting a totally weird graph that is not what im looking for and im unable to figure out the issue.

My Data set, average RT on x axis, Fraction on Y axis

[[image]

The graph that Im getting

[image]

What Im Looking for is, the RT on the x axis, and corresponding fraction on Y, so I can see from the graph which the most used/run RT load.

Help required.

[Smaller Data set selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcV5p.png)

[Graph I get with smaller amount of data selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Wgl.png)

What I want to get,

X axis values are 4150, 4250, .... 5050
Corresponding Y values are 0.000694, ....., 0.0296067.

Data Points (4150,0.000694)...(5050,0.0296067)

Comment: It almost looks like some odd clustered OR stacked bar that excel defaulted to. I would recommend reselecting your data and trying again. Try with just the first few rows, confirm it works, then expand to the rest of the rows. I'm able to replicate the issue with just a few rows... but can easily fix by selecting the right kind of bar chart. You should see two or three options when you create the clustered bar chart.

Comment: This may be easier to figure out if you could supply a smaller sample size, an image of the chart you currently get and an example of the chart you would like to get

Comment: Added in trial run with smaller data selected and also what im getting and a description of what I want to get

Comment: And when you right-click on your chart and select "change chart type", do you not see the option to change it to the correct bar chart? I'm able to replicate your issue and resolve it by doing that.

Comment: Right, Im able to see it. Thank you so much.

Comment: Cool. I think excel sometimes behaves this way when you have numbers on both axis. Just a guess, but at least it's easy to fix.